# How to query "any" in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm searching the web and can't find the right way to make a query in my MongoDB using Mongoose.

I want to perform a query if I receive the parameter:

```
async list(req, res) {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10, status = "" } = req.query;

    const orders = await Order.paginate(
      { status },
      {
        page: parseInt(page),
        limit: parseInt(limit),
        populate: { path: "user", select: "firstName lastName" }
      }
    );
    return res.send(orders);
  }
```

So for example, if status is not provided in the URL, I want to return all documents, and if I provide the status, return only the ones that match.

I can achieve what I'm looking for if I pass a status, but I can't return all documents if I don't pass a status. I tried with `""`, `undefined` and `null`, but none of them worked.

I also think the way I'm approaching it is not the best, because I'll have to declare in `const { page = 1, limit = 10, status = "" } = req.query;` all possible query parameters.

How should I handle it?

PS: I'm using `mongoose-paginate`, but they redirect the `query` documentation to the MongoDB documentation, so I assume it's the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you leave status out of the query or make it a regex query when empty (`/.*`)?  I've found it to be helpful to write a working MongoDB query before I implement the query in code (I use Java which is why I don't have any Mongoose-specific advice).

Comment: Yes, I actually want to leave it out of the query if it's not being received by URL. But I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Make a conditional to determine which query to send, empty query `{}` if status is not defined (or empty string as you have above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution. I could accomplish it using the spread operation of ES6:

```
async list(req, res) {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10 } = req.query;

    let filters = req.query;
    filters = { ...filters, page: undefined, limit: undefined };

    const orders = await Order.paginate(
      { ...filters },
      {
        page: parseInt(page),
        limit: parseInt(limit),
        populate: { path: "user", select: "firstName lastName" }
      }
    );
    return res.send(orders);
  }
```

This ensures that `undefined` objects won't make part of the query